# Use ngIf expression to conditionally show element based on a select option value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use a dropdown selection to conditionally show different elements. So when an option is selected, the DOM is given a different instance of a component based on the value from the dropdown.

I'm not sure if I'm binding the div that has the *ngIf correctly.

```
<!--Component.html-->
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="options">
<mat-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">
{{opt.viewValue}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div [(ngModel)]="options" *ngIf="options.value === '2';">
<component-with-table></component-with-table>
</div>
```

```
// Component.ts

options = [
{value: '1', viewValue: 'example string'},
{value: '2', viewValue: 'another example string'}
]
```

Comment: Look at the docs on how to use [**`ngModel`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following:
In .html File

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select (selectionChange)="ChangeOption($event)">
<mat-option   *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">
{{opt.viewValue}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div *ngIf="optionselected == '2'">
<component-with-table></component-with-table>
</div>
<div *ngIf="optionselected == '1'">
<component-with-table></component-with-table>
</div>
```

In .ts File

```
optionselected:string:"";
options = [
{value: '1', viewValue: 'example string'},
{value: '2', viewValue: 'another example string'}
]
```

//function

```
ChangeOption(event)
{
  this.optionselected = event.value;
}
```